# Intensity of Brightest Fringe of a multi-slit Diffraction

Tags: visible-light, interference, diffraction

Let's say we have a multi-slit experiment with N slits.Since the central fringe has the most intensity, is there an equation to calculate the intensity of central fringe in terms of the intensity of the original light wave?

I searched Fraunhofer Diffraction and Fraunhofer Diffraction Equation but neither of them helped me since they calculate the intensity of a fringe in terms of the intensity of the central fringe.Thanks.

Comment: The integral of the intensity over all the fringes will be equal to the total intensity of the light coming through the slits.

Comment: @JohnRennie Wouldn't be the intensity of central fringe higher than the intensity of original light wave?

Comment: Possibly, but it can't contain more energy. The integral of the intensity of the central fringe must be less that the integral of the intensity over all the slits that form the diffraction pattern. If it was that would mean there was more energy per second in the central fringe than was passing through the diffraction grating. However it's certainly true that if there are many slits, so a high overall area, the intensity at the central fringe can be higher than the intensity of the light hitting the diffraction grating.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes I know that the energy of central fringe has to be less than the energy of original light wave.However, I think the intensity of central fringe should be higher than the original light but the wideness of the fringe should also be inversely proportional to its intensity thus the energy of central fringe becomes less than the total energy. And also I think the intensity of central fringe should be always higher than the original light wave's since for an experiment with N number of slits there would always be constructive interference. Am I right?

Comment: The point is: do the math! :-) . You know the irradiance entering each slit; the rest is integrals.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I haven't taken calculus as a course, just tried to learn it on my own so if you could give me necessary knowledge about how to do the calculation, I may as well create the integration. Basically I don't know which way to take to do the calculation. I would be grateful if you can give me a helpful reference about this subject.

Comment: Do you have access to Smith, "Modern Optical Engineering," or any of the books by Grant Fowles or Hecht?  I recently tripped across a free text, http://optics.byu.edu/BYUOpticsBook_2013.pdf which looks pretty clear and detailed.